# subtraction within unions or joins in table php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

i have an income and expense table. i want to select them both in a single query and get the difference between the income.amount field and expense.amount field grouping by month. so that the query will return a result whereby the total of expenses amount from the total of income amount basing the calculation on month. i used used two methods but non worked. find the below:

```
SELECT *, count(*), sum(`transaction`.amount) as tiamount,  sum(expenditure.amount) as teamount, monthname(`transaction`.date) as mni, monthname(expenditure.date) as mne 
FROM `transaction`, expenditure 
WHERE month(expenditure.`date`)=month(`transaction`.`date`) and month(`transaction`.`date`)=month(expenditure.`date`) 
GROUP BY monthname(`transaction`.date) ORDER BY `transaction`.date Desc
```

the other is :

```
SELECT count(*), `transaction`.date, sum(`transaction`.amount) as tiamount, sum(`transaction`.amount - expenditure.amount) as diff, monthname(`transaction`.date) as mni 
FROM `transaction` left join expenditure on monthname(`transaction`.date) = monthname(expenditure.date)
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*), expenditure.date, sum(expenditure.amount) as teamount, sum(`transaction`.amount - expenditure.amount) as diff, monthname(expenditure.date) as mne 
FROM expenditure left join `transaction` on monthname(`transaction`.date) = monthname(expenditure.date)
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please, put the tables structure and test data to http://www.sqlfiddle.com/, so we could help you to write the request

Comment: ok. thanks, i have been there and have put the table sql and have built the schema. but when i run mysql i still get same result. what do i do next. thanks

Comment: what i really want is for the first row returned to substract the second row. thanks

Comment: You are supposed to get an error there. Just put the link to the fiddle into your question, so I could see, what error did you get.

Comment: am not getting any error. its actually displaying that exact thing i want. i know my query is not correct because am still new to mysql. here is the fiddle link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50d21
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50d21/1
the rows are multiplying each other and thereby given inflated figures. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks all. i solved the issue. each time the page is loaded, it checks to see if the table balance2 already exist, if it does it is dropped and recreated on the fly

```
mysql_query($query_truncate = "drop table IF EXISTS balance2");
    $create= "CREATE TABLE  balance2 (
    `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
     `count` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
     `month` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
     `amount` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
     `amount2` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
     `type` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
     `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
    ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1";
    mysql_query($create);
```

Then in used the `INSERT INTO...SELECT...UNION SELECT....`
to select from the expenses and income table to insert into the newly created balance table.

```
query_merge = "INSERT INTO  balance2 (count, date, amount, amount2, month, type)
(SELECT count(*), t.date, sum(t.amount),0 ,monthname(t.date), 'income'
FROM `transaction` as t group by month(t.date))
UNION
(SELECT count(*), e.date, 0,sum(e.amount) as teamount, monthname(e.date) as mne, 'expense'
FROM expenditure as e group by month(e.date))";
```

this worked perfectly as it gave me all the results i wanted. 
Thought it might help someone else. see ya